# Why do we "shed" blood, sweat or tears but not other things?

Tags: etymology, idioms, history

I found the following [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shed) of *shed* (the verb):

> 1. chiefly dialect :  to set apart :  segregate
> 2. to cause to be dispersed without penetrating
> 3. a.   to cause (blood) to flow by cutting or wounding
>
>    b.   to pour forth in drops *shed tears*
>
>    c.   to give off or out *sheds some light on the subject*
> 4. to give off, discharge, or expel from the body of a
>      plant or animal: as
>
>    a.   to eject, slough off, or lose as part of the
>      normal processes of life *a caterpillar shedding its skin*, *a cat
>      shedding hair*, *a deciduous tree sheds its leaves in the fall*
>
>    b.   to
>      discharge usually gradually especially as part of a pathological
>      process *shed a virus in the feces*
> 5. to rid oneself of temporarily or permanently as superfluous or unwanted *shed her inhibitions*, *the company shed 100 jobs*

Here, I am primarily interested in the third usage. We can *shed blood, sweat and tears* but not much else. Obviously, we can also *shed our clothes* or *shed light upon* but these are different meanings.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shed) of the word is:

> shed (v.) 
>       "cast off," Old English sceadan, scadan "to divide, separate, part company; discriminate, decide; scatter abroad, cast about," strong
>   verb (past tense scead, past participle sceadan), from Proto-Germanic
>   *skaithan (cf. Old Saxon skethan, Old Frisian sketha, Middle Dutch sceiden, Dutch scheiden, Old High German sceidan, German scheiden
>   "part, separate, distinguish," Gothic skaidan "separate"), from
>   *skaith "divide, split."
>
> According to Klein's sources, this probably is related to PIE root *skei- "to cut, separate, divide, part, split" (cf. Sanskrit chid-, Greek skhizein, Latin scindere "to split;" Lithuanian skedzu "I make
>   thin, separate, divide;" Old Irish scian "knife;" Welsh chwydu "to
>   break open"). Related: Shedding. A shedding-tooth (1799) was a
>   milk-tooth or baby-tooth.
>
> In reference to animals, "to lose hair, feathers, etc." recorded from c.1500; of trees losing leaves from 1590s; of clothes, 1858. This
>   verb was used in Old English to gloss Late Latin words in the sense
>   "to discriminate, to decide" that literally mean "to divide, separate"
>   (cf. discern). Hence also scead (n.) "separation, distinction;
>   discretion, understanding, reason;" sceadwisnes "discrimination,
>   discretion."

As far as I can tell, the third meaning of *shed* (in the quoted definition) is restricted to blood, sweat and tears. Why is that? What is the origin of the idiom *to shed blood*? I would guess that *shed blood* comes from the meaning *to scatter abroad* of the Old English word *sceadan*, if so, why is it so restricted today? Was it once a more common term? Could we once say *that I shed water on my garden* or *I shed the seeds in my field*?

Comment: But if we can shed skin and also hair, that invalidates your claim. I understand shed to mean that you lose (forever) *those* skin cells, *those* blood cells, those drops of tears and those hair strands. The very parts of our bodies which, funnily enough, continually renew themselves and get replaced. We don't shed teeth or bones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA shedding of that sort comes under the fourth meaning while shedding blood and tears is the third. Not sure I can put my finger on _why_ exactly but that is basically my question. Also, we shed other people's blood usually, not our own.

Comment: Well there aren't many other bodily fluids left to shed; apart from semen, and urine. Wherein semen is ejaculated and urine is passed.

Comment: If you are saying that shedding clothes is part of a different meaning, what else apart from blood, sweat and tears, would ypou expect to be able to shed? Waste products? I have never heard, incidentally of anyone shedding sweat!

Comment: @Mari-LouA indeed, but why would the usage be restricted to bodily fluids?

Comment: @WS2 neither had I but I looked it up and, apparently (here's [one example](http://progress-index.com/news/local-volunteers-shed-sweat-and-tears-on-mission-to-haiti-1.1032527)), it is used. As for other things, I would expect to be able to use it to mean _disperse_ if that's what the idiom comes from. Shedding clothes or skin means ridding yourself of them rather than _spilling_ or _spreading around_ which is the meaning I am after.

Comment: Who says it is restricted to bodily liquids but if you are interested in the third meaning, to cause sth to flow, then I can only see blood and tears fall into that category, profuse sweat can seemingly flow. I once knew a man who could *shed* buckets of sweat.

Comment: Anything liquid or granulated can be shed. As can many things metaphorically, like one's clothes or some light on the subject. It's from a common Teutonic root, with no other I-E cognates. It simply means to divide, with a subsidiary sense that one part (which may be fluid or plural) is to be discarded.

Comment: The idea of 'shedding light on a problem', seems interesting. The other meanings of 'shed' all involve discharging something, whether that be bodily fluids, clothing, possessions etc. But when light is shed it doesn't involve anything like that at all. It involves the introduction of something, quite the opposite of the normal 'shed'.

Comment: Don't forget the garden shed(s) too :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you see **shedding tears** and **shedding skin** as two distinct senses of the verb. That dictionary's division into senses seems somewhat arbitrary, especially since **shedding light** is gathered under the same sense as **shedding blood and tears.** The latter seem more related to the fourth sense, “to give off, discharge, or expel from the body of a plant or animal.” (Also note that **shedding light** invalidates the claim that the third sense only applies to blood, sweat, and tears.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye because _shedding skin_ seems to me to mean _getting rid of_ rather than _spilling_ or _dispersing_. It carries the connotation of ridding yourself of something, be it clothes or ideas or whatever. _Shedding light_ seems different because it does not carry this meaning of secretion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA apparently (and to my surprise) the two meaning [do not](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shed&allowed_in_frame=0) share the same origin which is why I did not mention it.

Comment: I don't agree that there's a neat distinction between “getting rid of” and “dispersing” when it comes to skin and tears. I suspect that the organization of that dictionary is encouraging you to make distinctions that aren't really that clear cut.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I won't press the point either, if there is a distinction it is not neat. I am thinking more in terms of blood, _shedding blood_ and _shedding clothes_ seem to me to be quite different if clearly related. Perhaps it is the poetic nature of shedding blood and tears as opposed to skin that makes e feel they're different. The dictionary does seem to agree with me.

Comment: @JohnLawler so the ancestral meaning already implied liquids? OK, that was not apparent from the etymology I quoted and makes more sense.

Comment: Note that [American Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shed) organizes things a little differently, and it gives leaves as another example of things that “pour forth, fall off, or drop out,” along with tears.

Comment: @BraddSzonye that's a very strange definition, I've never seen that usage. To me _all the leaves have shed_ would mean that the leaves themselves have shed something, not that they have been shed by the tree. Have you come across that usage before?

Comment: @terdon: I have. It is similar to, "tears were shed" or "tears have been shed."

Comment: @MrHen no it is not, in both those cases the tears have been shed by someone else not by the tears themselves. In the definition linked to by Bradd, the example was _all the leaves have shed_ and it seemed to mean _all the leaves have_ been _shed_ or that _the trees have shed all their leaves_. That is the usage I found strange.

Comment: @terdon: I didn't say that. I said it meant to separate. Liquids and granular substances are often involved, of course, and there are special verbs for them, but they're not specifically implicated in the original root for _shed_, afaik.

Comment: As a side note, it sounds perfectly acceptable to me to say that you shed water in your garden – it means that you pee in your garden. I would never use it to say simply that you water your garden (i.e., with a watering can or garden hose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because these usages of *shed* are assuming a few things about the objects being shed:

> a. to cause (blood) to flow by cutting or wounding
>
> b. to pour forth in drops *shed tears*

Both (a) and (b) require a liquid state in order to flow or drop and (c) is some form of luminance which you noted you don't actually care about. So you could say:

> (a) The cyborg shed oil from its veins.
>
> (b) The sky shed rain upon the fields.

These are non-standard in the sense that their usage is extremely uncommon but the meaning still fits.

To directly answer your question: You can shed blood, sweat and tears because they are liquids dispersed from cutting or wounding (blood) or things that pour forth in drops (sweat; tears). If anything else in the human body could do either of those things you could also shed them.

To prove the point:

> A urinary tract infection has been plaguing me for days. Yesterday I shed a mere three drops.

---

By the way, I have no idea where you copied your definitions from but the link you gave doesn't seem to match.

Comment: That's just it, the usages you suggest sound weird to me, I would not say _The sky shed rain upon the fields_. I cannot, however, explain _why_ I would not say that. If you say you would, then perhaps it is I who has a strange concept of the word. I guess I have not really expressed myself clearly, I find it interesting that the word seems restricted to liquids for example, any idea why? The etymology does not seem to restrict it to liquids and it is not so restricted when it means _to get rid of_ as in _shed clothes_. Thanks for pointing out the wrong link by the way, I added the right one.

Comment: The word really isn't restricted to liquids. *You* restricted it to liquids when you asked the question by only calling out those particular usages that required liquids. :) As for "the sky shed rain" sounding weird, I would say that it sounds *archaic*. I understand what was meant and that it is correct but would still wrinkle my nose at it and consider it awfully close to purple prose.

Comment: Btw, you can make it sound less awkward with context but I didn't feel like writing a short story around clouds shedding rain.

Comment: I would find it somewhat poetic, but not at all weird, to say that a cloud shed its raindrops.

Comment: Cystitis is one very very sore condition, and the sufferer does not shed drops of wee. The bladder is not blocked, it is just extremely painful to pass urine, which is expelled normally only in great discomfort. Where did you get the quote of the three drops of urine, if I may ask?

Comment: I made it up based on the experiences of a character in The Green Mile. If you know of a more appropriate condition I can edit it in. (Or you can; feel free.)

Comment: I did not restrict it to liquids, John Lawler [did](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133523/why-do-we-shed-blood-sweat-or-tears-but-not-other-things?noredirect=1#comment276143_133523). Anyway, for some reason Bradd's suggestion of a cloud _shedding its raindrops_ sounds less weird than _the cloud shed its rain_ which probably indicates I am making this whole thing up. In fact, that seems more and more likely as more of you chime in with different takes on the word :). Still, you have to admit it is a strange word!

Comment: "He weeps like a wench that had shed her milk" _All's well that ends well_ Act iV, scene iii

Answer (score -1):

Great or good or OK points. But I think there's more, something deeper - a relationship between pain - emotional or physical - and the word shed.

**Sweat**: I've never heard of *shedding sweat* but let's take that one first. Interrogation might, say, be sweaty from a physical response to the emotionally painful stress of verbal pressure to give in, or the tension between giving in and physically induced pain. Strenuous exercise or other kinds of hard, physical effort, as well as exposure to excessive heat - all of which can cause varying levels of pain - will usually result in sweat as well. So sweat generally comes from stress.

**Blood:** Shedding it, willingly or otherwise, self-inflicted or inflicted upon others, is deliberate. (If there's blood from an accident, we don't usually say *shed*.) Shedding blood can obviously cause physical pain, and may also involve emotional pain.  But with both sweat and blood, both the causes and results are usually Deliberate and Intended, either by us or others.

**Tears**: (My search for the relationship of the word shed to this one is what brought me to this page.) Both physically and emotionally generated tears can result from all the same kinds of painful stress that cause sweat. And our emotional response to the shedding of blood can easily evoke tears. All that's a given. But my focus on shedding tears is on the emotions that lie beneath them. Those emotions are, of course, sadness and happiness, and all the words we use to describe their varying intensities. Those emotions have causes but they and the tears are Involuntary Responses, not Deliberate, unless one's faking it.

But why do we sometimes *shed tears* and not just *tear up*, *cry*, *weep* or *sob*? Here's where I relate this idiom to *shedding clothes* or *a snake shedding its skin*, though both of these are deliberate. And here's where my reasoning is admittedly winging it, but I think valid.

The idea is that our tears of happiness or sorrow are emotionally excreting something from us, ridding us of something, releasing something from us - and that something is pain.  ..  OK, yes, we don't usually think of happiness as painful. But tears shed from - Out Of - happiness are often from the sense of release and relief at the realization that something painful has ended or is ending. And tears we shed when we feel grief, sorrow and sadness are a release of some of the pain, letting it out drop by teardrop, or maybe by a torrent.  ..  So, I believe, we “shed tears” to shed ourselves of emotional (well, and sometimes physical) pain.